# How to search unique tuples in multiple list of tuples in python

Tags: python

If I have

```
a = [("1","2"),("5","6")]  [("3","4"), ("5","6")] [("5","7"), ("2","3")]
```

How do I search through the lists of tuples to get a ordered unique list of tuple say:

```
B = [("1","2"),("5","6"), ("3","4"), ("5","7"), ("2","3")]
```

---

```
Unique = []
for tuple in a:
    If tuple not in Unique:
        Unique.append (tuple)
```

gives list of tuples same as a.

EDIT:

Since none of the solution actually worked for me I am giving the actual problem:

I have a text file with four sentences,say:

1. This is utf-8 line1
2. This is eng line 1
3. This is utf line 2
4. This is eng line 2

I extract line 1 and line 3 to a variable (utfvar) and line 2 and 4 to (engvar). Then create tuples with:

```
UtfEng = list (zip (utfvar,engvar))
```

print `UtfEng` is:

```
[('This','This'), ('is','is')...('line','line'),('1','1')]
[('This','This'), ('is','is')...('line','line'),('2','2')]
```

I want to extract unique tuples from this as:

```
[('This','This'), ('is','is')...('line','line'),('1','1'),('2','2')]
```

Comment: What exactly is `a`? Is it a list of lists of tuples? What you have now isn't meaningful.

Comment: are `("5","6")` and `("6","5")` should be treated as duplicates?

Comment: That's not valid Python, and it doesn't iterate over the sublists.

Comment: @chepner They are list of lists containing tuples.. consider I have four sentences in a file and I do strip and  list(zip(line)) I get  two lists of tuples. I want to generate one list of unique tuple

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am editing lines in a file and reading it by line and saving in a variable and when I do: 
print (myvar)
[('བུམོ', 'bhum'), ('གསང', 'saN'), ('བ', 'wa'), ('ཀུན', 'kun'), ('གྱི', 'ghi'), ('ཡོན', 'yOn'), ('ཏན', 'tOn')]
[('ཡོན', 'yOn'), ('ཏན', 'tOn'), ('དང', 'dhaN'), ('གདུང', 'dhuN'), ('ཤིང', 'SiN'), ('ཕྱུག', 'Chuk'), ('པའི', 'pai'), ('དྲུང', 'DhuN'), ('དྲུང', 'DhuN')]
type (myvar) <class 'list'><class 'list'>

Answer (score 1):

as @jonrsharpe wrote on comment, this is not a valid python.

but let's say you have three lists.

```
>>> a = [("1","2"),("5","6")] ;b= [("3","4"), ("5","6")];c= [("5","7"), ("2","3")]
```

merging those,

```
>>> a+b+c
```

will give you,

```
[('1', '2'), ('5', '6'), ('3', '4'), ('5', '6'), ('5', '7'), ('2', '3')]
```

then you can

```
>>> list(set(a+b+c))
[('2', '3'), ('1', '2'), ('5', '7'), ('5', '6'), ('3', '4')]
```

which will give you unique tuples.

[documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this format of you input data (since the code you posted was mangled):

```
a = [[("1","2"),("5","6")], [("3","4"), ("5","6")], [("5","7"), ("2","3")]]
```

First flatten the list, and then do what you did before:

```
flattened_list = [item for sublist in a for item in sublist]

Unique = []
for pair in flattened_list:
    if pair not in Unique:
        Unique.append(pair)

print(Unique)
```

Answer (score 0):

> They are list of lists containing tuples...  I want to generate one
>   list of unique tuples

The solution using `collections.Counter` object:

```
import collections

a = [[("1","2"),("5","6")], [("3","4"), ("5","6")], [("5","7"), ("2","3")]]
c = collections.Counter([t for l in a for t in l])
unique_tuples = [t for t in c.keys()]

print(unique_tuples)
```

The output:

```
[('3', '4'), ('5', '7'), ('1', '2'), ('2', '3'), ('5', '6')]
```

https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: they are not really list of list it seems since when I do print(type(myvar)) I get two lists:   <class 'list'> <class 'list'>